# Django Tables 2 Filter field, but use the display name?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I've got this model:

```py
DRAFT = 'draft'
IN_PROGRESS = 'in_progress'
FINISHED = 'finished'

STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (DRAFT, 'Entwurf'),
    (IN_PROGRESS, 'In Arbeit'),
    (FINISHED, 'Erledigt'),
)


class Invoice(TimeStampModel):
    status = models.CharField('Status', choices=STATUS_CHOICES, max_length=50)
```

and this filter I've build with the django tables 2 plugin:

```py
class InvoiceFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

        class Meta:
            model = Invoice
            fields = {
                'name': ['icontains'],
                'status': ['icontains'],
            }
```

My filter gets rendered without a problem on my page and I can use it. The problem right now is though if I try to search for a status using the german word, like for example `Entwurf` the filter always returns me no item. BUT if I filter for `draft` I get all the items which have this status. So my question would be: how can I tell my filter to look for the display name of my status field?

Or even better: would it be possible to just make a select out of the status field instead of a normal search?

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I should have looked a little closer into the docs of django tables 2. I found my solution:

```py
class InvoiceFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        status = django_filters.TypedChocieFilter(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

        class Meta:
            model = Invoice
            fields = {
                'name': ['icontains'],
            }
```